# broken pipe in win32 (WinAPI)

Tags: winapi

I have followed the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx) for reading from a pipe, but ReadFile fails and GetLastError() shows me that the pipe is broken.
I have created and used (successfully) a pipe earlier in the program, but I closed all the handles and used entirely new variables for the new pipe just to be sure.
Any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2 = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2 = NULL;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr2; 
STARTUPINFO si2;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi2;

ZeroMemory( &si2, sizeof(si2) );
si2.cb = sizeof(si2);
ZeroMemory( &pi2, sizeof(pi2) );
//create pipe
saAttr2.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
saAttr2.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
saAttr2.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 
CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2, &saAttr2, 0);
//create child process
bSuccess = FALSE;
memset(szCmdLine, 0, MAX_PATH);
sprintf(szCmdLine, "ffmpeg.exe -i output.mp3");
ZeroMemory( &pi2, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );
ZeroMemory( &si2, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
si2.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
si2.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2;
si2.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si2, &pi2);
//read from pipe
CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2);
memset(chBuf, 0, BUFSIZE);
for (;;) 
{ 
  bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
  [bSuccess is 0 and GetLastError() returns error 109]
  ........
```

Comment: please post minimal but full source code so we can use our compilers to help find the problem. full = we can compile and run it. minimal = there is only enough code to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Broken pipe" is a normal error when the other end closes the pipe. In your case, this either means there is no "other end", or the other application hasn't written anything to its `stdout`.
I've modified your code to be a compilable test case – there are two cases in which `ReadFile` fails without having read any data for me:

- `CreateProcess` failed. I've added an `assert` so that problem will be recognizable. It would of course result in a broken pipe.
- The process does not write anything to standard output. It might instead write to its standard error stream. I've redirected `stderr` to the pipe as well, and as my `echo` example shows, this will receive both streams on the other end of the pipe now.

Code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 200

int main(void)
{
    BOOL bSuccess;
    char szCmdLine[MAX_PATH];
    char chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dwRead;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2 = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2 = NULL;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr2; 
    STARTUPINFO si2;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi2;

    ZeroMemory( &si2, sizeof(si2) );
    si2.cb = sizeof(si2);
    ZeroMemory( &pi2, sizeof(pi2) );
    //create pipe
    saAttr2.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
    saAttr2.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
    saAttr2.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 
    assert(CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2, &saAttr2, 0));
    //create child process
    bSuccess = FALSE;
    memset(szCmdLine, 0, MAX_PATH);
    sprintf(szCmdLine, "cmd /c echo output && echo error>&2");
    ZeroMemory( &pi2, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );
    ZeroMemory( &si2, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    si2.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
    si2.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2;
    si2.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2; // also add the pipe as stderr!
    si2.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    assert(CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si2, &pi2));
    //read from pipe
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr2);
    memset(chBuf, 0, BUFSIZE);
    for (;;) 
    { 
        bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd2, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        printf("%d %lu 0x%08lx\n", bSuccess, dwRead, GetLastError());
        if (bSuccess)
            printf("\t'%*s'\n", (int)dwRead, chBuf);
        else
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the *very* late accept, but I had a hard time finding the problematic code and seeing what actually went wrong with it. The problem was indeed the fact that the called executable, ffmpeg.exe, wasn't printing anything to stdout.