# ReadFile hangs when reading from pipe in VBA

Tags: winapi, vba, readfile

Premise: Using VBA (Access), run ftp and pass commands to it using CreateProcess and Read/WriteFile.

Objective: Write to the ftp process stdIn to send commands and read the stdOut to determine information from ftp directory structure, using pipes. Also, to understand the correct way to format my code when using Windows API functions and determine if another method (using API console commands) might be more appropriate.

What I've tried:
The following code hangs on either of the ReadFile or WriteFile calls. I'm not sure if I should be using sync or async and where to put my commands I'm sending. I placed the ReadFile call in the wait loop as mentioned in reference [2].

```
Public Sub ExecCmd(cmdline As String)
Dim proc As PROCESS_INFORMATION
Dim start As STARTUPINFO
Dim hReadPipe1 As Long, hReadPipe2 As Long
Dim hWritePipe1 As Long, hWritePipe2 As Long
Dim ret As Integer, buff As String, lngBytes As Long
Dim lpCurrentDirectory As String

'Create pipes for reading/writing to console
If CreatePipe(hReadPipe1, hWritePipe1, vbNull, 0&) = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "createpipe failed" 'Stdout
If CreatePipe(hReadPipe2, hWritePipe2, vbNull, 0&) = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "createpipe failed" 'Stdin

' Initialize structures etc
start.cb = Len(start)
start.lpTitle = "CBase Console"
start.wShowWindow = 0
start.hStdOutput = hWritePipe1
start.hStdError = hWritePipe1
start.hStdInput = hReadPipe2
lpCurrentDirectory = "H:\"
buff = Space(260)

If CreateProcess(0&, cmdline, 0&, 0&, 1&, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0&, _
    lpCurrentDirectory, start, proc) = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "createprocess failed"

buff = "echo hello world" & vbCrLf
ret = WriteFile(hWritePipe2, buff, Len(buff), lngBytes, vbNull) 'code hangs here

Do 'or code hangs on readfile if writefile is removed
    If ReadFile(hReadPipe1, buff, Len(buff), lngBytes, vbNull) = 0 Then _
        MsgBox "readfile failed"
    ret = WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, 0)
    DoEvents
Loop Until ret <> 258

ret = CloseHandle(proc.hProcess)
ret = CloseHandle(proc.hThread)
ret = CloseHandle(hReadPipe1)
ret = CloseHandle(hWritePipe2)
End Sub
```

Related articles (from which I couldn't glean the answer, due to my inability to convert code format):
[1]: [cmd.exe will not terminate under certain conditions when launched with the CreateProcess function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866158/cmd-exe-will-not-terminate-under-certain-conditions-when-launched-with-the-creat) 
[2]: [Win32 ReadFile hangs when reading from pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816962/win32-readfile-hangs-when-reading-from-pipe)  
[3]: [broken pipe in win32 (WinAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803214/broken-pipe-in-win32-winapi)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are spawning an external ftp.exe process instead of implementing the FTP protocol directly in your code? You can use Microsoft's WinInet API, which natively supports FTP, if you don't want to use WinSock directly.

Comment: I was initially using a WScriptExec to run it but I don't want to see the window and I didn't want to output the result of multiple commands to a file (using .Run). I will give the WinInet API a shot. Any idea why the above was failing?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm making progress using the method you recommended a while back. This was what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code did the trick. This was all done in MS Access 2007. Thanks @RemyLebeau for pointing me in the right direction with the WinInet API.

```
'Declare wininet.dll API Functions
Public Declare Function FtpCommand Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpCommandA" (ByVal hConnect As Long, ByVal fExpectResponse As Boolean, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpszCommand As String, dwContext As Long, phFtpCommand As Long) As Boolean
Public Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" (ByVal sAgent As String, ByVal lAccessType As Long, ByVal sProxyName As String, ByVal sProxyBypass As String, ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function InternetConnect Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetConnectA" (ByVal hFTP As Long, ByVal sServerName As String, ByVal nServerPort As Integer, ByVal sUsername As String, ByVal sPassword As String, ByVal lService As Long, ByVal lFlags As Long, ByVal lContext As Long) As Long

Public Sub ftpUpdateP()
Const NUMBYTES As Long = 1020
Const MAX_PATH As Long = 256
Dim hOpen As Long, hConn As Long, hOutConn As Long
Dim buffer As String, bytesRead As Long
Dim iUnit As Integer, sCode As Variant
Dim strOut As String, arrOut() As String

'Open internet connection
hOpen = InternetOpen(vbNullString, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
DoEvents
If hOpen = 0 Then Exit Sub

'Connect to ftp
hConn = InternetConnect(hOpen, "ipaddress", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "user", "password", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0)
DoEvents
If hConn = 0 Then GoTo ErrorConnectToFTP

For iUnit = 1 To 2
    For Each sCode In Array("I", "P")
        strOut = ""

        'Get directory contents
        Call FtpCommand(hConn, True, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, "NLST /p/u" & iUnit & "/CY" & getCurrentCycle(iUnit) & "/" & sCode & "/d.*", 0, hOutConn)
        DoEvents
        If hOutConn = 0 Then GoTo ErrorDirList

        'Read the FTP response to listing the target directory contents
        Do
            buffer = Space$(NUMBYTES + 4)
            Call InternetReadFile(hOutConn, buffer, NUMBYTES, bytesRead)
            strOut = strOut & TrimNull(buffer)
        Loop Until bytesRead = 0

        'Close handle to dirlist; create date from directory name
        InternetCloseHandle hOutConn
        arrOut = Split(strOut, Chr(13))
        strOut = Mid(arrOut(UBound(arrOut) - 1), InStrRev(arrOut(UBound(arrOut) - 1), "/") + 1)
        strOut = Eval("#" & Mid(strOut, 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(strOut, 7, 2) & "/" & Mid(strOut, 3, 2) & " " & Mid(strOut, 10, 2) & ":" & Mid(strOut, 12, 2) & "#")

        If sCode = "I" Then dateLastI(iUnit) = strOut Else dateLastP(iUnit) = strOut
    Next
Next

dateLastPUpdate = Now
ErrorDirList:  InternetCloseHandle hConn
ErrorConnectToFTP: InternetCloseHandle hOpen
End Sub
```